# How to call curl command for API from python script

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, curl, https

I want call the curl function python script to call a API. How can this be done.

I excuted from the terminal its works fine.

```
curl --header "Authorization: Api-Key ABCD1234"  https://api.lat.com/western/v1/forecasts?locodes=PLWRE,DEHLI


{"results":[{"place":{"type":"locode","value":"PLWRO"},"measures":[{"ts":1571896800000,"t2m":10.72,"t_min":10.53,"t_max":11.99,"wspd":8,"dir":"SE","wgust":12,"rh2m":87,"prsmsl":1012,"skcover":"clear","precip":0.0,"snowd":0,"thunderstorm":"N","fog":"H"}]},{"place":{"type":"locode","value":"DEHAM"},"measures":[{"ts":1571896800000,"t2m":10.79,"t_min":10.3,"t_max":10.9,"wspd":13,"dir":"ESE","wgust":31,"rh2m":97,"prsmsl":1008,"skcover":"partly_cloudy","precip":0.0,"snowd":0,"thunderstorm":"N","fog":"H"}]}]}sh-4.2$
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `requests` library to make the cURL call.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.lat.com/western/v1/forecasts?locodes=PLWRE,DEHLI"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Api-Key ABCD1234"
    }

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```

You can get a JSON formatted response using `response.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this resource:
https://curl.trillworks.com/

It simply utilizes the requests module to convert your curl statement into arguments.